# Run anaconda through bash file

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, anaconda

I have made a script in python that crops an image.
I am using Anaconda for that and Python 2.7 in Windows

What i want to do is to run this script for a whole folder with images, so i was thinking of making a bash file. 
I followed [these steps](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) and *bash on Ubuntu on Windows*. I installed again Anaconda for linux and some libraries needed but now i am getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0shU.png) even if i have installed the same package as in Windows.

Any ideas? Or maybe another ways to do it on Windows where my script is already running well on Anaconda?

Comment: Do you have the path to Anaconda's python.exe set in your system's path? For example, what happens when you try to type `python` in windows terminal or powershell and hit enter?

Comment: On window prompt i'm getting:
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (Default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

On ubuntu:
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul 2 2016, 17:42:40) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be what you're looking for as you asked for assistance with your bash script. However, you could modify your python script to crop all the images in a specified folder using the glob function. You can run it on windows with anaconda installed.

glob returns a list of all the file names matching the unix style flags and wildcards. A sample of how this might work for your scenario may be:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob("c:/path/*")   # where path is the path to your images to be cropped

# then run your script on all the images to be cropped
for f in files:
    # Run python script
```

Comment: It is exactly what i needed in order to make it run without a bash file. Thank you very much for your help!